# Malloc() creates space for single struct, not array of structs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, struct, malloc, arrays

I've been banging my head against this problem all day, I would be very grateful to anyone who could help out.

Here's the deal - I'm trying to create a dynamic C array using malloc().  This array will hold CGPoint structs, which I start building and assigning right after the array is built.  Here's the code:

```
CGPoint* tempVertices = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint) * 4);  //defining a collision frame
tempVertices[0] = CGPointMake(37, 46);
tempVertices[1] = CGPointMake(69, 40);
tempVertices[2] = CGPointMake(48, 6);
tempVertices[3] = CGPointMake(17, 10);

//Then I pass the pointer to my array off to a setter...
[self setVertices: tempVertices];
```

However, when tempVertices gets created, it seems that I'm only getting space for one CGPoint:

```
int test1 = sizeof(CGPoint);        // 8
int test2 = sizeof(tempVertices);   // 4
int test3 = sizeof(*tempVertices);  // 8
```

When stepping through with the XCode debugger, it shows that `tempVertices` is a pointer to a `CGPoint`.  When I set `tempVertices[0]`, the `CGPoint` that `tempVertices` points to recieves that value, which is reflected in the debugger.  Where did my other 3 slots go?  `tempVertices` seems to be pointing to a singe `CGPoint` instead of an array.  I want the array.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  I know that there are other ways to fix this using C++ or other objects, but I want to stick to C if possible.

Thanks in advance!

---

Update :

To answer zpasternack, `setVertices:` is a custom written setter.  And I don't know how / if it knows how big the incoming array is.  I'm trying to understand straight C stuff better, so insights/explanations regarding the proper way of passing a dynamic C-array as an argument are highly appreciated.  Here's what the setter looks like :

```
- (void) setVertices:(CGPoint*) val {
    _vertices = val;    //_vertices is a member variable of the type CGPoint* 
    //...calculate a centroid, other stuff...
}
```

If needed, I could wrap my CGPoints in NSValue objects and use an NSArray instead, but I sure would like to know the right way of doing it in plain ol' C.

Thanks to everyone who has commented - you guys are great :)

Comment: As others have pointed out, your malloc() is probably working fine.  I'm left wondering about the call to setVertices.  What does that function look like?  Is it a synthesized setter, or custom written?  How does it know how big the array is?

Comment: Updated the post to address your comment - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after your edit I think I see what's going on.  That code, exactly as you've written, should work OK.  Xcode won't show you the values of any of those CGPoints, because it doesn't know it's an array, just a pointer to a single CGPoint.  But it's there.  Set a breakpoint right after you call `setVertices:`.  At the gdb prompt, print some of those values.

```
(gdb) print _vertices[1]
$2 = {
  x = 69, 
  y = 40
}
(gdb) print _vertices[3]
$3 = {
  x = 17, 
  y = 10
}
```

Correct, see?

That's not to say there aren't issues here.  For one thing, `setVertices:` is leaking that memory.  You're allocating memory for `tempVertices`, holding onto that pointer, but not freeing it anywhere.  The next time you call `setVertices:`, you'll have a leak.

A bigger issue is that nobody knows how many CGPoints are in that array, except the code that allocated the memory for it.  Will it always be 4 CGPoints?  What happens if somebody accesses `_vertices[5]` or `_vertices[27]`?  Bad things, if you didn't allocate that much space for them.

Is there a requirement that this be a plain C array?  Like, these points are going to get passed to OpenGL or cocos2d or something?  If not, you might consider using some kind of array class for it.  Because these aren't NSObject-derived objects you're storing, you can't use an NSArray.  You could use a `std::vector`, if you don't mind dragging in a buncha C++.  I probably would not do that.

If you're set on sticking with a C array, you should probably do some work to try to make the interface less error prone.  Like I mentioned before, you'll need to track the size of the array.  Perhaps you could add a parameter to setVertices: representing the number of CGPoints that the array holds.  Then other parts of the code that access `_vertices` could check that to make sure they're not walking off the end of the array.  And, like I mentioned before, make sure you free that memory before you reassign the pointer.

Messing about with pointers is fraught with danger.  Tread carefully, there be dragons there.

Comment: You, my friend, are a gentleman and a scholar.  Now I know what I need to do, and I feel like I understand the system a lot better thanks to your excellent help :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

On your 32 bit machine, you're getting exactly what you expect. sizeof(tempVertices) is the size of the pointer, while sizeof(*tempVerices) gives you the size of a CGPint (probably two ints). You can't get the size of an allocated array with sizeof(). The value is only known at run-rime, and sizeof() is a compile time operator.

Comment: `CGPint` sounds much more fun than `CGPoint`! :) And it’s two floats, actually.

Comment: I'd rather have two pints than two root beer floats. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the info on sizeof(), Richard. I'll definitely bear that in mind moving forward!

Answer (score 1):

The malloc is allocating enough space for 4 GCPoint structs and returning a pointer to the allocated space.

The first is at tempVertices + 0. It's tempVertices[0].

The second is at tempVertices + 1. It's tempVertices[1].

The third is at tempVertices + 2. It's tempVertices[2].

The fourth is at tempVertices + 3. It's tempVertices[3].

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `sizeof()` to determine the size of an array allocated at runtime.

Have you actually had trouble assigning new `CGPoint` objects into your array? Does `CGPointMake()` perform any allocation of its own?

Comment: `CGPointMake()` is an inline function that creates an automatic `CGPoint` structure, assigns its arguments to the structure members, and returns the temporary structure. It performs no heap-allocation on its own.

Comment: Correct - I can't assign new CGPoint objects into the array.  It takes the first one, for index 0, then seemingly ignores assignments to 1-3. In the XCode debugger, the array is shown as type CGPoint* and looks like a single CGPoint.  Bavarious - thanks for the info on CGPoint!